# Should I interpret the scaled or the standard model in SEM (lavaan)?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm attempting to fit a structural equation model in `lavaan`. My model looks like this:

```
model <- '
  # measurement model
    OCI =~ OCI_ordering + OCI_obsessing + OCI_checking + OCI_hoarding + OCI_washing + OCI_neutralizing
    SPQ =~ SPQBR_NCA + SPQBR_IRS + SPQBR_ESA + SPQBR_MT + SPQBR_OS + SPQBR_EB + SPQBR_UD
  # regressions
    IMIS_negval ~ OCI + SPQ + Music_ed_year
    INMI_freq_num ~ OCI + SPQ + Music_ed_year
    INMI_ep_num ~ OCI + SPQ + Music_ed_year
  # residual correlations
    OCI ~~ SPQ
    IMIS_negval ~~ INMI_freq_num + INMI_ep_num
    INMI_freq_num ~~ INMI_ep_num
'
fit <- sem(model, data = data1, ordered=c("INMI_freq_num", "INMI_ep_num"))
summary(fit, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

As some of my variables are not normally distributed and I have a few ordinal variables, `lavaan` uses the DWLS estimator. As such, for the Chi-square statistics and model fit indices, a standard and a scaled model appears in the output:

```
Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        62

  Number of observations                          4301

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                              1199.752    1676.356
  Degrees of freedom                               110         110
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.728
  Shift parameter                                           28.507
    simple second-order correction 

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.956       0.856
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.952       0.843

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.048       0.058
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.046       0.055
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.050       0.060
```

Should I be looking at the scaled or the standard model values when trying to interpret my model fit? If I should be looking at the scaled values, how can I improve my model fit?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be looking at the scaled or the standard model values when trying to interpret my model fit?

When a scaled statistic is provided by default, it is because the standard statistic is known to follow a different distribution than the expected one.  In this case, the scaled statistic corrects for the sample statistics of latent response variables (i.e., polychoric correlations) being estimated with less precision than for observed variables.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3162326/

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be looking at the scaled or the standard model values when trying to interpret my model fit?

I agree 100% with @Terrence's recommendation that scaled statistics should be used when categorical data is fit using [polychoric correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation)$^1$. For more information on scaled test statistics for categorical data when polychoric correlations are used, see Savalei & Rhemtulla (2013).

> If I should be looking at the scaled values, how can I improve my model fit?

Why do you need to improve fit? I ask because if your current model exhausts all theoretically/substantively valid paths, then there is nothing to change—your model simply does not have good fit. I say this because you could easily find alternative parameterizations of your model that would lead to better fit using `modindices()`.

$^1$ Note, the recommendation to use appropriately scaled statistics has also been argued for [structural equation models (SEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) fitted to continuous data when multivariate normality is believed to hold (Maydeu-Olivares, 2017).

**References**

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2017). Maximum likelihood estimation of structural equation models for continuous data: Standard errors and goodness of fit. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 24(3), 383-394.

Savalei, V., & Rhemtulla, M. (2013). The performance of robust test statistics with categorical data. British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 66(2), 201-223.